# How do I resolve "no package called '.GlobalEnv'" error in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm getting a confusing error while using RStudio. When I use the command line, in the middle of typing a command (never while executing a command), R throws the following error:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘.GlobalEnv’

I am using R version 3.2.3 and RStudio version 0.99.491; I have tried to re-install RStudio and to delete settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried reinstalling; the behavior persisted.

Comment: Can you post the version numbers? You may be mistaken about they being the latests.

Comment: You probably need to take this to RStudio support.  Search their forum first, you might find it's been answered already.

Comment: Added R and RStudio version above; OS is El Capitan (10.11.2)

Comment: I see no reason. I would recommend to follow @RichardScriven's advice.

Answer (score 14):

Look at the tabs that open at startup.
In my case, it was because there was a debugging tab opened and RStudio was trying to load it at startup. I just closed it and that error stopped.

Comment: I just ran into this problem and your answer here has solved it.

Comment: Same here, an inspection window opened from a previous session caused a `Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘debugging’` message upon starting RStudio... until I closed inspecting window.